# Organic Group visible only by authenticated user

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I want to make the list of OG visible only to authenticated user so they can request membership. I have created a view but it only display group the user is already member of.

When I change the group visibility from * Private - accessible only to group members* to *Public - accessible to all site users* this make the group visible to anonymous user too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to deny access to anonymous user.

In your Organic Group content type admin interface (admin/structure/types/manage/committee) a new `ACCESS CONTROL` tab appears. Unckeck `anonymous user` for the view `View any committee content`.

If `authenticated user` is check it will over-right Organic Group settings (ie. the Private / Public will have no effect and the content will be accessible to all authenticated user).

[source](https://drupal.org/node/1512758)